# Git - transferring all commits to another branch and creating a new master

Tags: git, branch, branching-strategy

*(There's a lot of similar questions on this, and I've also read through various docs, but I can't find anything answering this specific issue.)*

Given a repository with no remotes and no branches, with 20 commits on master.

The intent is to end up with an *empty* master, and all the commits on develop, but without a messy history.

Is there a difference between:

```
git branch --move master develop
git checkout --orphan master
```

And:

```
git checkout -b develop 
git merge master
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^20
```

?

The first option seems the simplest way to do this, but I've not seen it suggested anywhere - all the various things I've been reading tend to use variants of the second option (or rebasing, which I don't think applies here).

Does the first option do what I think it does, and does it have any benefits/drawbacks compared to the second option?

Is there an alternative even better way to achieve this?

Comment: I think the reason you found the second sequence is that `git checkout --orphan` is a relatively new addition to `git`, added in part to address scenarios like this. The second sequence partially works (as noted in Blakes answer), but isn't quite sufficient to accomplish the goal.

Comment: Thanks for info - it is indeed new enough that I need to upgrade Git, since it just said `error: unknown option 'orphan'` when trying to do it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Branches are just commit pointers. You get into some weird territory when there's nothing at which to point. Honestly if you're just looking to get a "clean" workflow history, so the first commit of any significance is a merge from `develop` into `master`, add an insignificant commit to `master` first:

```
git branch --move master develop
git checkout --orphan master
git rm -rf . ;# abandon the staged, orphaned changes
echo README > README ;# put something in this working directory
git add README && git commit -m "Initial commit of <my_project>"
```

Why commit something? Because once you run the `--orphan` checkout, you won't be able to do anything meaningful with the `master` branch. Try it yourself:

```
$ git checkout --orphan master
Switched to a new branch 'master'
$ git checkout develop && git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

How about a merge?

```
$ git checkout --orphan master
Switched to a new branch 'master'
$ git merge develop
fatal: Non-fast-forward commit does not make sense into an empty head
```

No dice. The only real way around this is to commit something, anything, to that empty branch.  The moment you do, you can merge `develop` any way you'd like:

```
$ git merge develop
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 README | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
```

And the log:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline
*   867a1f9 Merge branch 'develop'
|\  
| * 22df145 README
* 15ba82a Initial commit of test project
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher, that all makes sense. Having a single new commit on master is fine (and more consistent with my other projects too).

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is that the second version won't work. HEAD^20 won't resolve to anything on a history with only 20 commits, so `git reset --hard HEAD^20` will fail.

Your initial version should work fine. If the second version had worked, I can't see there being a significant difference between the two.